# Obtener nombres de los empleados cuyo nombre termine en 'O' y tenga sólo 5 letras

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que no me sale, se trata de obtener los nombres de los empleados cuyo nombre termine en 'O' y tenga solamente 5 letras.

El problema es que la columna tiene de nombre NOMEM y contiene el apellido y el nombre separado con una coma, ejemplo:
SEGURA, SANTIAGO.

He estado intentando hacerlo con SUBSTR y con NOMEM LIKE pero no consigo averigarlo...

```
SELECT
NOMEM AS NOMBRE
FROM
    TEMPLE
WHERE
    NOMEM LIKE ', %O_____'
ORDER BY NOMEM;
```

Llevo bastante tiempo del día con este problema, ojalá alguien me ayude un poco, gracias.

Comment: si el nombre tiene que terminar con O entonces, alcanza con %O, no??? luego de eso, con otra query, podes verificar que todo lo que esta despues de la , mide 5.. y listo.. no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba usar una expresión regular como:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(NOMEM, -5) AS NOMBRE
FROM TEMPLE
WHERE
    LOWER(NOMEM) REGEXP '[ ,][a-z]{4}o$'
```

Para este caso el campo `NOMEM` debe:

- Terminar con o.
- Tener 4 caracteres antes de la `o` para hacer un total de 5.
- Tener un espacio o una coma antes de los 5 caracteres `[ ,]`.

Puedes ejecutar una prueba acá http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c148af/2/0

Alternativamente si quieres evitar errores porque tal vez al final el usuario agregó un espacio en blanco, puedes usar `TRIM`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(NOMEM), -5) AS NOMBRE
FROM TEMPLE
WHERE TRIM(LOWER(NOMEM)) REGEXP '[ ,][a-z]{4}o$';
```

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En la consulta actual que tienes estás buscando los caractéres "___" despues de la "O" y no te va a traer nada, en MySQL hay una función CHAR_LENGTH() que obtiene la longitud de los caracteres de un campo, intenta algo así

```
SELECT * FROM `TEMPLE` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(NOMEM) = 5 AND NOMEM LIKE '%%O';
```

Comment: dijo que nomem tiene apellido y nombre...

Comment: Ya está solucionado, muchas gracias.